# Numpy compare array to multiple scalars at once

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

and I want to compare it to some scalar; this works fine like

```
a == 2 # [False, True, False]
```

Is there a way I can do such a comparison but with multiple scalars at once? The default behavior when comparing two arrays is to do an elementwise comparison, but instead I want each element of one array to be compared elementwise with the entire other array, like this:

```
scalars = np.array([1, 2])
some_function(a, scalars)
[[True, False, False],
 [False, True, False]]
```

Obviously I can do this, e.g., with a for loop and then stacking, but is there any vectorized way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Outer product, except it's equality instead of product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html):

```
numpy.equal.outer(scalars, a)
```

or adjust the dimensions and perform a [broadcasted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) comparison:

```
scalars[:, None] == a
```

Comment: The first one is a Python loop, very inefficient.

Comment: @liliscent: What? No it's not. Why do you say it's a Python loop?

Comment: Ah, I initially tried adding an axis of dimension one and then doing the comparison, but I did it like `scalars[None, :]` instead, which doesn't work. I didn't know about `equal.outer`, though!

Comment: @user2357112 I always have the impression that the first one is very slow... I tested just now, it's significantly slower than the broadcast. But maybe not a Python loop... not sure.

Comment: @liliscent: When I time it, it seems to have extra startup cost, but the loop speed seems the same.

Comment: @liliscent did you try avoiding the slow name lookup by caching `equal_outer = numpy.equal.outer`?